# Minimal description for tree selection

Tags: algorithms, trees

If you have a tree, where nodes can be either selected or not selected, and you wanted to describe which nodes were selected or not you could either

1. List all the selected nodes and infer the others are not selected.
2. Say a node and all it's children are selected or deselected then apply these rules to build up the tree selection. The rules would need to be applied in order.

[image: Tree]

For example, if you had the tree above, and you wanted to describe a selection you could say:

1. Nodes 9, 17, 22, 20, 4, 5 are selected. (therefore 3, 6, 7 are not selected)
2. Or the equivalent description: 9 and descendants selected, 3 and descendants not selected, 6 and descendants not selected, 5 and descendants selected.

In my use case, where a tree will have large sections selected or deselected, using the second method to describe the selection is much more efficient.

Rather than reinvent the wheel, is there a name for this kind of tree selection description? My googling has let me down. Are there even more efficient ways to describe the selection?

If it helps at all, the use case is a client and a server, where they both have the same tree, and the client needs to tell the server which parts are selected and deselected. The trees can be very large.

**Update:**
In response to @D.W. who asked for more details.

The problem I'm trying to solve is how to efficiently send a description of which nodes in a tree are selected or deselected. Both sender and receiver have a copy of the same tree.

I have a rich client, which has a tree control. A user can select and deselect nodes on the tree. The tree can have 100K+ nodes and a user will generally select sections of it and maybe deselect some descendants.

Once the user is finished with their selection they'll press apply and send it off to the server. If they've selected the root node, as an extreme example, the differences between sending the description of the selection with method 1 or method 2 is quite obvious. Because the tree isn't programmatically selected, and so it's incredibly unlikely that a user will select and deselect parents and children in some alternating pattern across a massive tree, method 2 will always be cheaper.

Once the server receives the description of which nodes are selected and deselected from the client it needs to apply this description to its own tree so it has a copy of what the client is looking at.

It feels like this would be a common enough problem that someone would recognise it, but I'm starting to doubt it! :)

Comment: The second method is not very efficient either. Consider all the internal nodes to be selected, and the leaves nodes to be *not* selected. The second method would be as inefficient as the first method. Note that in this example, there is indeed a large contiguous section as "selected".

Comment: My general advice is: rather than asking for the name of something, ask about what problem you want to solve.  If you knew the name, what would you do with it?  If you ask how to solve a concrete problem, then you have two ways to be successful: one is we tell you it's a standard problem known under a particular name, and then you know how to solve it; or there is no standard name but someone tells you how to solve it anyway. If you just ask for a name, you miss out on the second opportunity.